# CheckDate,cheking days and month in 2019

Tags: java

I have a task that I should write a program that the user writes
a month and a day. Then the program should print about t if it
is a valid day of the year. We assume the year is 2019, which
is not a leap year. For example, if the user writes month: 3 and
day: 21, then this is a valid day, but if the user specifies
month: 2 and day: 30, this is not a valid day because 30th
February is not a valid date.
I should use Array but I don't know how to use it :/

```
public class Main {                                                     

    public static void main(String[] args) {                            
           int daysInMonth[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};   
           int monthInYear [] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,,7,8,9,10,11,12};           
           int i=0;                                                       
           for(i=0;i<"month"-1;i++);                                                                                                                                                                   
         }                                                                                                                                   
      }
```

Comment: start by import java.util.Scanner and print out a question and get the month from the user, print out another question and get the day.  If this is for a  high school java class you can assume the user will input an integer and not worry about error checking unless you are told differently. Then create two loops one to check if the month is valid and one to check if the day is valid

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that the year is 2019 and the user only enters integers.

First you must create a Scanner and *int* variables to store what the user enters.

```
//import Scanner

public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {       


      int daysInMonth[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};   
      int monthInYear [] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};

      //Create a Scanner

      System.out.println("Enter month:");
      //ask user for month    

      System.out.println("Enter day:");                   
      //ask user for a day     



   }       


}
```

After you get the Scanner imported and the user can enter the month and day you can check if the month is valid. If the month is valid then you can compare the days to see if they are valid.

```
      if( ) {  //check if month entered is a valid month                                               

          //if month is valid, check the day by comparing the day entered by user and 
          //daysInMonth[](the number of days for that month)


      }
      else
         System.out.println("Invalid month");
```

When done correctly a sample run would look like.

```
     ----jGRASP exec: java Main
Enter month:
2
Enter day:
30
Valid month but Invalid day of the year!

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

 ----jGRASP exec: java Main
Enter month:
2
Enter day:
28
Valid Month and day of the year!

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

 ----jGRASP exec: java Main
Enter month:
13
Enter day:
2
Invalid month
```